# ScrollIntoView() with routerLinkActive and ngFor

Tags: angular, dom, ngfor, angular-router

I have list with routerLinkActive:

```
<div *ngFor="let experimentType of experimentTypeList">
  <a class="d-flex align-items-center experiemnt-link-button selectable-item"
     [routerLink]="getScenarioExperimentTypeLink(experimentType)"
     routerLinkActive="link-button-selected">
     {{ experimentType.name }}
  </a>
</div>
```

When one of the link will be activated I want scroll it into view (via scrollIntoView()).

I can do this manually:

```
<div (click)="scroll()">scroll()</div>

  public scroll(): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.link-button-selected').scrollIntoView()
  }
```

But I don't understand how do this programmatically.

I tried:

1. AfterViewInit, OnChanges
2. listen changes on @ViewChildren('rla'),
3. Listen this.router.events

Nothing works. It is triggered before directive adds class.

Comment: Maybe if you can put it in stack blitz we can help more

Answer (score 0):

In your html, you do something like this (I added `#somethingToTarget`):

```
<a class="d-flex align-items-center experiemnt-link-button selectable-item"
 #somethingToTarget
 [routerLink]="getScenarioExperimentTypeLink(experimentType)"
 routerLinkActive="link-button-selected">
 {{ experimentType.name }}
</a>
```

In your component code:

```
@ViewChild('somethingToTarget') somethingToTarget: ElementRef;
```

And after you can call:

```
this. somethingToTarget.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
```

Comment: yes, i tried. Main problem where write code:
this. somethingToTarget.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });

Comment: The easiest I can think of if to take a different approach, instead of using [routerLink], you can use a (click) event on your link, import Router in your ts file and use the navigate function that returns a promise when the navigation is successful, you can then call scrollIntoView